# What's hatched on my rose?

Tags: indoors, roses, bugs

While watering my rose plant this morning, I noticed it was covered in tiny brown bugs:

[image]

They're on most of the leaves of the plant. What are they? Is there anything I can do? The plant is currently kept inside - should I move the plant outside to avoid an infestation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree they do look like spider mites - however, you are in the UK, and red spider mite is only an issue on indoor plants here, never outdoors. I suggest you relocate your rose to the outdoors, and the spider mite should vanish on its own over a week or two, but if you happen to have any Roseclear Ultra, or another insecticidal spray, use that just in case the webbing is coincidental and what's actually on the plant are aphids. I note also there is some yellowing of areas of leaf on the plant - it's obviously in a pot if its indoors, so if you can find a sunny spot in the garden to plant it in the ground, it should grow more healthily.

Comment: Garden? I'll put it on the balcony :-)

Comment: @TomMedley Ah! You and me both then... roses don't last long in pots in terms of years, they don't like 'em, but you'll have it for a while

Comment: It was a cheap Sainsbury's pot, which I think might have run its course. Oh well!

Comment: @TomMedley oh I see - they're just meant as temporary visitors really, but you could pot up into something larger, see if it flowers again or next year.

Comment: Zooming in on the picture, they definitely look like mites of some kind to me, and with the webs, I concur that they're some kind of spider mite. :) Our spider mites in my section of Idaho in the USA are almost always invisible, though, for some odd reason, even though they're probably our most prevelant pest (so, although I know spider mites generally are often visible, because I'm not used to seeing them, those look huge to me).

Comment: @Shule Red spider mite I'm pretty sure....probably on the plant at point of sale, acquired from the greenhouse in which it would have been grown

Comment: Make sure that you harden this plant before taking out of doors.  Bring it back in reversing the process for winter unless you plant it in the garden.  I would certainly spray with Neem first.  Do it in the tub and get all surfaces to include under the leaves.  Allow to dry, then turn the shower on, soak and allow to drain.  Then start the hardening off to take it out on your balcony.  Do not allow to sit in a saucer of water.  Are there areas on your balcony that are shaded the entire day?  You can put your plant in that shade without hardening.  Then allow a bit more sun.  Retreat if needed.

Comment: @stormy - no need for hardening here at the moment - chances are its hotter outdoors than it is in - 30 degrees C here at the mo at 8.45 pm! Not much sun forecast either, just heat...

Comment: Even humans can get a bad sunburn in overcast.  The best place is a covered porch or balcony.  Temperature isn't as important as the light rays from the sun.  I want to see if this rose is OUT of that dang foo foo foil paper the florists sometimes use to sell plants.  Florists or at least their suppliers know that sitting in water the foil holds in will kill the plant.  The buyer thinks it is their fault and buys another.  grrrr.  Same with the packet they give for fresh flowers?  It actually shortens the life of fresh flowers!  Corruption is everywhere!!  Grins!

Comment: @stormy - its in a pot from a supermarket, meant to be a temporary bit of colour in a house display, they're quite cheap to buy, bit like azaleas or poinsettias in the winter. You just bin 'em when they stop flowering usually.

Comment: Exactly, I spent a year as a florist in a huge grocery store/chain.  I was a bit 'unusual'...my bottom line was higher than all the other stores in the chain combined.  Had a full blown nursery in the parking lot, sold huge bouquets that the customers chose flowers fillers wrapped in cool newspaper and raffia.  Painted a life size cherry tree on the entrance wall and had it change with the seasons.  Dried flowers or sent to hospitals instead of throwing them away.  Huge return clientele.  Amazing that I wasn't LOVED. Grins.  Those foils for pots are awful.

Answer (score 3):

They look like rose spider mites.  You can use a miticide or insecticidal soap to get rid of them.  Repeat after 14 days to get the eggs that hatch.

http://www.gardeningknowhow.com/ornamental/flowers/roses/rose-spider-mites.htm